# Array/List for implementing DBMS (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, sql-server, list

I am fairly new to programming, only been programming for around four to six months.

I want to find a way to build tables in java and have methods to join two different tables and perhaps where clauses as well (similar to SQL). I realize there probably exists some library which can get the job done, but I want to implement this on my own. I want to be able to support columns of string and int types as well.

As a starting point I was thinking of representing my data as a collection of rows. I was initially thinking of maybe creating a column class as well, but with how I want join to work (similar to SQL) this seems like a headache and unnecessary.

Given that I only want to use lists/arrays, would the collection of rows be a good idea? Also, if i do something like String[][] and want to have an int column, how can I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably _not_ be looking to do table joins in your Java code.  This is what your database is suited for, and it is why databases were created.  If you need to represent a record in your Java code, then `Object[]` would be the simplest way to do this.  In the meantime, try to narrow down your question if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "This is what your database is suited for, and it is why databases were created." It seems like this is what he wants to create.

Comment: Well I want to support natural inner joining of two tables given that the only type possibilities of columns are string and int. I dont mean that the string column can hold ints and vice versa, just that the table can have string columns and int columns. So to better put my question, how can I implement this using only arrays/lists?

Answer (score 0):

I think deciding whether to use ArrayList or Object[] will be the least of your concerns. However, if we assume that the number of columns is unchanging for each table, then it makes sense to store a row internally as `Object[]` and wrapped of course with a sensible Row object providing utility methods. Then since the rows can be inserted and deleted, it makes sense to store them internally as a `List<Row>`, wrapped of course with a sensible Table object.

Comment: Do you mean number of columns unchanging as in pre join? If so then yes. Though I would like to support something like  Table Z1 has column A and B. Table Z2 has columns A and C. Then, the cartesian product of the tables would return a table where the size could very well be different from A,B or C.

Comment: @JohnFang Like I said, deciding which internal data structures to use is the least of your problems. No offense but I think you have chosen a project too difficult for your current skill level. And no one here is going to write it for you step by step.